# How to match mulitple cells from Sheet1 to multiple cells from sheet2 in Excel including having multiple conditions met?

Tags: excel-formula, nested, nested-loops, multiple-matches

Sheet1 Columns:
A1- Account Number
B1- Invoice/Credit #
C1- NDC
D1- Item Description
E1-Invoiced Quantity

Sheet2 Columns:
A1- Invoice Number
B1- NDC
C1- Qty

In another column in sheet1, I would like to do the following:

IF Invoiced Quantity = 0
OR
Item description = "text"
OR
Item description = "text"
OR
Item description = "text"
A. True- return "zero invoices"
B. False- IF B2 from sheet1 can be found in the Invoice Number column from sheet2
AND
IF C2 from sheet1 can be found in the NDC column from sheet2
AND
IF E2 from sheet1 can be found in the Qty column from sheet2
A. True = "Match"`
B. False = "Review"

So the options in the new column should be zero invoices, match, or review.

I have tried many things with no success. Please help. If possible, explain it as well. :-)

Comment: maybe share some examples of what you want to achieve.